# Обновление php чата по ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Помогите, пожалуйста сделать оптимизацию. Сейчас чат работает по принципу отправки раз в секунду запросов. Хочу сделать так, чтобы  запросы на подтягивание всех сообщений отправлялись только если есть хотя бы одно непрочитанное. Для этого так же раз в секунду отправляю запрос на подсчёт непрочитанных:

```
$sql = "SELECT readed FROM chat WHERE idto='$currentloginid' && readed!='0'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
$updates=mysqli_num_rows($result);
} 

if ($updates==0) {
    require_once "chatupdate.php";
    die();
} else if ($updates>=1){
    require "chatupdate.php";
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы если updates==0 (то есть непрочитанных в таблице нет). require_once "chatupdate.php" (в chatupdate.php выполняются более тяжелые запросы по получению сообщений) выполнялся только один раз но результат при этом, в следующую секунду, сохранялся на странице?

Comment: сохраните в кэш результат и при отсутствии непрочитанных сообщений берите значения из кэша

Comment: если не сложно, сможете примерно написать, как это сделать?

Comment: Запишите результат получаемый в скрипте `chatupdate.php` в файл. В отсутствии сообщений выводите содержимое этого файла, а не скрипта `chatupdate.php`

Comment: понял, а как в кеш записать? можно элементарный пример?

Comment: используйте функции `file_put_contents` и `file_get_contents`.